# Can I have my deleted questions undeleted?

Tags: support, closed-questions, deleted-questions, privileges

Can I have any questions that I deleted counting towards my question ban undeleted so I may work on them to get my asking privilege back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Undeleting all of them at once would not help, but rather create a few issues:

- if you don't edit them quickly, the system will automatically delete them within a few hours
- if you edit them quickly, the chances that they will remain of poor quality are high, and this will be an issue for everyone, as you will not get out of the ban, and the other users will get annoyed by them.

I also see that you started working on the non deleted questions you have, I can thus propose you the following:

1. finish working on the questions you can access (be careful to not invalidate answers already given, as this would be a problem and we would be forced to undo your edits)
2. once you're done with those, if the ban is still in place, we can undelete one question at a time (you will tell us which one you would like to work on with a comment down here)

These are your questions currently deleted:

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36849/how-fast-would-frisbee-have-to-spin-to-not-tumble

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34190/can-a-flying-saucer-be-practical-in-aviation

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33672/how-does-drag-differ-on-blimps-in-ideal-gas

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31571/where-is-the-calmest-place-on-earth-as-far-as-wind-year-round

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26325/effect-of-internal-forces-to-a-gliders-descent

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26324/reactive-force-on-an-aircraft-dropping-a-package

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25499/high-altitude-unpressurized-vehicle

Comment: I 've improved the ones with negative scores as much as I can that have not been deleted. Thank you for taking your time for this. The 3 rd has been revised and is active, 4th asked in Earth Science and has a great score, 5th been answered in space se,  The others I am ready to work on them. I know it may not help but but feel free to reinstate the ones left that could be improved. and thanks again.

Comment: I don't remember posting (number 5 or 6) this or why. This isn't my question. I may have cross posted before i understood how all of this works but his is not mine.

Comment: @Muze, as I mentioned, is you that decide which you want to work on, and one at a time. If you decide that 5 and 6 are not worth your time, fine.